# SBT: Can I have a test suite/manifest and still run individual tests on demand?

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, scalatest

Is this possible in SBT 0.13 with ScalaTest 2?

1. `sbt test` <-- Runs `MasterSuite` which nests A, B, C.
2. `sbt test-only A`  <-- Runs only A.

I can accomplish #1 with this below, but it prevents #2. Is it possible without tagging or annotating hundreds of tests?

`testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(_.matches(".*MasterSuite$")))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what #1 prevents in #2.

Perhaps you mean it prevents `sbt test-only D` because D is not in the MasterSuite?

By the way you could probably create a [Configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#custom-test-configuration) to handle the MasterSuite.

So that you could use:

```
sbt master:test
sbt test
sbt test-only package.A
```

Perhaps it solve your problem?

Comment: 1) If I use a Tests.Filter to make #1 work, it prevents #2 from working. This is because the filter is applied to anything passed to test-only as well.

Comment: 2) I didn't think about creating a new configuration. That might be a suitable compromise. Thank you, I'll have a think about that.